# Dispatching Redux actions on location change with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-router-dom

I am using React and Redux for a search application. Using `react-router-dom`, I'm routing `/search/:term?` to a `Search` component:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/search/:term?" component={Search} />
    <Redirect to="/search" />
  </Switch>
```

```
const Search = (props) => {
  const { term } = props.match.params;
  return (
    <div>
      <SearchForm term={term}/>
      <SearchResults />
    </div>
  )
};
```

When a user submits a search in the `SearchForm` component, I'm dispatching an action to submit the search query. I'm also initiating a search in the constructor if a term is given, initially:

```
class SearchForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const term = props.term ? props.term : '';
    this.state = {
      term: term,
    }

    if (term) {
      this.props.submitSearch(term);
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.term) {
      this.props.submitSearch(this.state.term);
    }
  }

  render = () => {
    <form
      onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
      ...
    </form>
  }
}
```

I'm using `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`, so the URL updates when the search is submitted.

**The problem happens when the user navigates Back in their browser.** The URL navigates back, the props update (i.e. `props.match.params.term`), but the search does not resubmit. This is because the `submitSearch` action only gets dispatched in `SearchForm.constructor` (search on initial loading if a term is in the URL) and `SearchForm.handleSubmit`.

What is the best way to listen for a state change to `term` when the URL changes, then dispatch the search action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would retrieve the route parameter in `componentDidMount` since you are pushing a new route and therefore reloading the view.

Inside your SearchForm it would look like this.

```
state = {
  term: '';
}

onChange = (term) => this.setState({ term })

onSubmit = () => this.props.history.push(`/search/${this.state.term}`);
```

And in your SearchResult :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchResults(this.props.term)
}
```

A nice thing to do would be to keep the SearchResult component dry. There are several ways to achieve that, here is one using [higher order components aka HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) :

```
export default FetchResultsHoc(Component) => {

  @connect(state => ({ results: state.searchResults }))
  class FetchResults extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
      dispatch(fetchResults(this.props.match.params.term))
    }

    render(){
      <Component {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  return FetchResultsHoc;
}
```

That you would then call on your SearchResult component using a decorator.

```
import { fetchResults } from './FetchResultsHoc';

@fetchResults
export default class SearchResult extends React.PureComponent { ... }
// You have now access to this.props.results inside your class
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to dispatch `submitSearch` in the `componentWillRecieveProps` lifecycle method if the new props don't match the current props:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.term !== nextProps.term) {
    this.setState({
      term: nextProps.term,
    });
    this.props.submitSearch(nextProps.term);
  }
}
```

Then, instead of dispatching an action on form submission, I push a new location onto the `history` and `componentWillReceiveProps` does the dispatching:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.state.term) {
    this.props.history.push('/search/'+this.state.term);
  }
}
```

This solution feels a little wrong, but it works. (Other's would seem to agree: [Evil things you do with redux — dispatch in updating lifecycle methods](https://hackernoon.com/evil-things-you-do-with-redux-dispatch-in-updating-lifecycle-methods-ad116de882d4))

Am I violating a React or Redux principle by doing this? Can I do better?